# .* not capturing commas correctly

Tags: regex, ruby

My regex does not properly handle commas in a line.

```
if line =~ /^.*,(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}),(\d+:\d+),.*,(\d+),.*,(.*) && (.*),Other,Other.*$/
```

I am reading a file line by line that should look like:

```
"",2019-06-14,01:30,,27,"",Episode Name && Series Name,Other,Other,LOCAL
```

However, if the series name has a comma in it, eg. "Busy Electron, The", the regex will only capture the "The" and not the entire name.

Comment: Ideally, I would be able to capture all the fields so that the episode name that is captured would be "Busy Electron, The", but at the moment, the regex is only capturing "The".

Comment: Whenever you give an example you should always show the desired result as a valid Ruby object. Also, all data inputs should be valid Ruby objects (you need to surround your string with single quotes) and you should assign a variable to each, so readers can refer to those variables (e.g., `line`) in their answers. Presumably, `line = '"",2019-06-14,01:30,,27,"",Episode Name && Series Name,Other,Other,LOCAL'`. Is the desired result an array containing the date, time and so on? Please edit as appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be the expression we might be in search of here, yet not the right method:

```
"(.*?)",([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})\s*,([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}),(.*?),([0-9]+),"(.*?)",(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*)
```

Excluding the last field, we'd just implement a lazy quantifier `(.*?)` for those fields which we'd not be validating.

`(.*)?` does not work, since it would make the entire capturing group lazy rather than `.*`.

Before, it would get to `?`, `.*` has already swiped our string to the end and has collected all chars except for the newlines.

If we wish to add or reduce the constraints, we can do so, such as:

```
"(.*?)",\s*([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})\s*,\s*([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})\s*,(.*?),\s*([0-9]+)\s*,"(.*?)",(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*)
```

#### Test

```
re = /"(.*?)",([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})\s*,([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}),(.*?),([0-9]+),"(.*?)",(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*)/m
str = '"",2019-06-14,01:30,,27,"",Episode Name && Series Name,Other,Other,LOCAL

"some things we wish here",2019-06-14,01:30,some things we wish here,27,"some things we wish here",Episode Name && Series Name,Other,Other,LOCAL'

# Print the match result
str.scan(re) do |match|
    puts match.to_s
end
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hWtI7i/1/)

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: Awesome thank you very much! I think what i needed was this: "(.*?)",([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})\s*,([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}),(.*?),([0-9]+),"(.*?)",(.*?) && (.*?),(.*?),(.*) because the "&&" was supposed to be a delimiter between the episode and series name, but not all episode/series names have commas in them. I don't quite understand why this works, could you explain why "(.*?)" works but not "(.*)"? Just for my own curiosity.